# Semi-Opaque Text Background?

Tags: css, text, background-image, opacity

So I have a page with a background image, and when I put text over it, I'm seeing a semi-opaque text background that is making my page background image render differently, but only under the text in question.

Does anyone know how to fix this? It is making my page look like there is a semi-transparent headed that I do not want there.

I've linked to my project below.
[Codepen Project](https://codepen.io/valsburger/project/editor/AEYBNP)

```js
$("#nav-status").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#navigation").toggle();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1671394/wood-dark.png");
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}


/*mobile rules*/

@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
  #nav-status {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  }
  ul {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  li h1 {
    font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  ul li {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 32px;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
  }
  li a:link,
  a:visited,
  a:active {
    color: white;
    font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  li a:hover {
    color: #ba1d30;
    font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .content h1 {
    font-family: "Bangers", cursive;
    color: #ba1d30;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  }
}


/*desktop rules*/

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  #nav-status {
    display: none;
  }
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  li h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
  ul li {
    color: white;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 2px;
  }
  li a:link,
  a:visited,
  a:active {
    color: white;
    font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  li a:hover {
    color: #ba1d30;
    font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-style: italic;
  }
  .content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 20%;
  }
  .content h1 {
    font-family: "Bangers", cursive;
    color: #ba1d30;
    font-size: 5em;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Portfolio Template</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1671394/nerdcatkiss.png">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bangers|Oswald" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <body>
    <div>
      <a href="#" id="nav-status"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1671394/nerdcatkiss.png" alt="Kissy Cat"></a>
      <ul id="navigation">
        <li>
          <h1>Explore</h1>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" target="framename">Web Pages</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Games</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Productivity</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Category 4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Valarie Pisarcik</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

  <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: add `min-height: 100vh;` to body tag

Comment: Great, that worked! Can you explain to me what that is and how it works?

Comment: vh is a unit meaning viewport height. so the height of the screen. By doing 100vh you are giving it a 100% screen height

Comment: you are applying the background twice, to html and also to body .. so both images give you this effect and the down have only one image because the body ends when the content ends ... adding my css will make it equal to html and always having both background

Comment: by the way the your initial image have this opacity effect because it's transparent ;)

Comment: so a semi transparent used twice will increase opacity